# testing Api's firebase and xamarion form

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to write Api's using xamarion and do crud Operation in firebase real time database, But this is my first time to deal with it now i want to test this api's without need to write xaml code and create form for example, How can I do it ? in node js and web development we use postman, here what we can do ?

this is my code for example :

```
 public async Task<bool> Save(Specalist specalist)
    {
        var data = await firebaseClient.Child(nameof(Specalist)).PostAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(specalist));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Key))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
 public async Task<List<Specalist>> GetAll()
    {
        return (await firebaseClient.Child(nameof(Specalist)).OnceAsync<Specalist>()).Select(item => new Specalist
        {
            Email = item.Object.Email,
            Name = item.Object.Name,
            ID = item.Object.ID
        }).ToList();
    }

    public async Task<bool> Update(Specalist specalist)
    {
         await firebaseClient.Child(nameof(Specalist)+"/"+specalist.ID).PatchAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(specalist));
        return true;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Delete(string id)
    {
        await firebaseClient.Child(nameof(Specalist)+"/"+id).DeleteAsync();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: you could write a C# console app, or a similar app in any language that Firebase supports

Comment: I did, But i want to test it without needs to eritea xaml code

Comment: What are you talking about?  A console app doesn't use XAML

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/unit-testing